# Help with HTML parsing and sending requests to a web server

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib, httplib

I'm working on a small project and I've run into a small problem.  The script I have needs to fetch a website and find a specific value in the source HTML file.  The value is like this:

```
id='elementID'> 

 <fieldset> 
  <input type='hidden' name='hash' value='e46c945fe32a3' /> 
 </fieldset>
```

Now I'm been trying to use the ElementTree library to parse the HTML document to find the value but I haven't been very successful.  I'm really new to Python so I don't really know what to do next.

I've been using httplib and urllib/urllib2 to connect to the website and POST my login details and things like that but I really don't know how to get that value from the page.  I thought I could send a request for the input named 'hash' but I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider looking at the [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) library - it's designed to be quick and easy to use.

Comment: Thanks, that's probably exactly what I need but I'm not sure how to actually put it to use.  Could you give me some hints on how to actually USE BeautifulSoup to search the HTML document?

Comment: Take a look at the Quick Start portion of the documentation: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Quick Start